# How can i limit users to only view index.php but not limit <link> <Script src> and php from accessing thos files

Tags: php, .htaccess

i havnt realy tried much besides

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files "index.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

it worked but it also prevented php and link tags from accesign other files

Comment: What are you aiming to do? What is the goal? An example will help , your question as it stands is too broad and unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write any script or link in your code, they won't send request to server themselves, it's actually user sending request for that resource. If there is a link to any resource to any part of your server and you want it to be served, you must let browser access that and browser means user.